# Has any Science Fiction/Fantasy novel won any of the big 3 literary awards?

Tags: books, awards

The big 3 awards are the [Man Booker International Prize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_Booker_International_Prize), the [Pulitzer Prize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulitzer_Prize), the [Nobel Prize in Literature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nobel_Prize_in_Literature).

I can't recall any novel, classified as Science Fiction/Fantasy by author/general public, that has won any of these awards.  Are there any?

Comment: Is there a reason you do not include the Newberry (_A Wrinkle in Time_, _Mrs. Frisby and the Rats of NIMH_), Caldecott (_Jumanji_), or Hans Christian Andersen Award (as an international award for rarely-translated literature, I'm less familiar with the authors/works, but I would be very surprised to find not a single sf work in there - Quentin Blake, who illustrated for Roald Dahl's fantasy work, has won it)?

Comment: @Joe: Children's literature is typically classified separately from SF. Of course, the boundaries are hardly clear.

Comment: @Gilles: While I'll admit the boundaries are less clear because more children's literature will drag in the fantastic without becoming fantasy, the examples I gave all land smack in the middle of SF.

Comment: The science fiction writer [Michael Shaara](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?1260) won a Pulitzer Prize. Unfortunately he won it for a non-sf novel, though his sf was also quite good.

Comment: Whaaat? Tolkien did not win a Nobel prize?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That's difficult to answer, because the SF-ness of a work is not an objective criterion. There's the added difficulty that the Nobel prize is usually awarded to an author for the sum of his work, not to a specific work.

Taking having an entry on [ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/) as a criterion, here's a list (not exhaustive, I just tried names that I thought might be considered ISFDB material). They tend not to be published as SF — though some came too early and are now considered classics, and some would probably be published as SF if they weren't from a non-habitually-SF writer. Several are typically classified as [magical realism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magical_realism) — when supernatural elements are used in a story but play a background, decidedly metaphorical role.

- [Rudyard Kipling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudyard_Kipling), Nobel 1907, well-known for stories involving talking animals (most famously [*The Jungle Book*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?39134)), but these are generally considered children's literature.
- [Selma Lagerlöf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selma_Lagerl%C3%B6f), Nobel 1909, now mainly remembered for [*The Wonderful Adventures of Nils*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?776445), a children's book involving a child transformed into a pixie, but that book may not have played a big part in her being awarded the prize.
- [William Faulkner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Faulkner), Nobel 1949, Pulitzer 1955 for [*A Fable*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Fable_%28novel%29) and 1963 for [*The Reivers*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Reivers). [*A Fable*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1982) is sometimes classified as speculative fiction.
- [Isaac Bashevis Singer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Bashevis_Singer), Nobel 1978, sometimes incorporated supernatural elements from Jewish folklore in his [tales](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?1383).
- [Gabriel Garcia Marquez](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel_Garc%C3%ADa_M%C3%A1rquez), Nobel 1982, played on the passage of time in [*One Hundred Years of Solitude*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?154348).
- [William Golding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Golding), Nobel 1983, wrote some [stories](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?31734) with SF-nal elements, such as [*The Inheritors*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Inheritors_%28William_Golding%29).
- [Günter Grass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%BCnter_Grass), Nobel 1999, occasionally used [SF-nal elements](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?3582) in his novels, most famously [*The Tin Drum*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tin_Drum) (whose protagonist decided to stop growing up at age three).
- [Doris Lessing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doris_Lessing), Nobel 2007, wrote a few [stories](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?831) that can be considered SF.
- [*Midnight's Children*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?4042) by [Salman Rushdie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salman_Rushdie), Booker 1981, uses an SF-nal element (telepathy).
- [*The Blind Assassin*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?186366) by [Margaret Atwood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margaret_Atwood), Booker 2000, has a science-fiction story within the story, which turns out to be closely linked to the main story.
- [*The Famished Road*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?15892) by [Ben Okri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ben_Okri), incorporates supernatural elements from Nigerian folklore.
- [*The Amazing Adventures of Kavalier & Clay*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?904238) by [Michael Chabon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Chabon), Pulitzer 2001, is technically not SF, but full of SF-nal elements.
- [*The Road*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?263611) by [Cormac McCarthy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cormac_McCarthy), Pulitzer 2007, is post-apocalyptic and thus firmly SF.

None of the authors in this list are generally considered SF writers, though Michael Chabon comes close.

Comment: I think I did not make my question clear enough, I meant science fiction and fantasy.

Comment: @apoorv020: I didn't distinguish between the two in my answer. Read “speculative fiction” for SF.

Comment: I find this list pretty tendentious myself.  First of all, I don't think those authors who write in magical realism share much of the same methodology or audience with SF/fantasy authors.   Also, the two Jewish lit authors I most recognize, Singer and Chabon, incorporate totally magical elements into modern and realistic set pieces, something I think disqualifies them from being considered either SF (where the bounds on the imagination are constrained by scientific laws) or fantasy (where the landscape is totally fictional).  IMO.

Comment: @Billare: [ISFDB's policy](http://www.isfdb.org/wiki/index.php/ISFDB:Policy#Definitions)  includes magical realism in SF (= speculative fiction). I didn't make any conscious judgement on the SFness of a work when compiling my answer: as I mentioned, I followed ISFDB. There may be a bias in that I browsed through the lists and only checked names that caught my attention.

Comment: Margaret Atwood issued a denial about writing SF, if I remember correctly.

Comment: I went ahead and added Marquez to the answer, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @apoorv020: Sure, go ahead if you find other writers or works that meet my criteria, but please respect the format.

Comment: @Billare: Well, _The Yiddish Policeman's Union_ won the Nebula and Hugo, so I think you'd be hard-pressed to argue it's not sf.

Comment: @apoorv: Atwood denies writing science fiction because her definition of science fiction requires the work not be set on Earth. (I think it's a poor definition.) But she does openly refer to her work as "sf" or "speculative fiction".

Comment: Besides his talking animal stories, Kipling wrote a number of [science fiction](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?19024) and [fantasy](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?19584) stories.

Comment: Since this answer was written, [Kazuo Ishiguro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazuo_Ishiguro) won the 2015 Nobel Prize.  He writes in many genres, but his 2005 novel *Never Let Me Go*, is definitively science fiction — for instance, it was shortlisted for the Arthur C. Clarke award.

Answer (score 8):

The Road by Cormac McCarthy won the Pulitzer Prize a few years back.

The Nobel Prize for Literature is not awarded on the basis of a single novel but is given to an author for their contribution to the world of literature. A quick scan of the list of Laureates suggests Doris Lessing who wrote the [Canopus in Argos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canopus_in_Argos) sequence which is most definitely Science Fiction.

The Booker prize list didn't suggest any Science Fiction although The Famished Road by Ben Okri has some fantastic elements (the Spirit World is perceived by the main character).

Comment: Doris Lessing's genre according to wikipedia:Modernism, Postmodernism, Sufism, Socialism, Feminism, Science fiction. But point about the road well taken.

Answer (score 3):

[Harry Martinson](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Harry_Martinson) was a Nobel laureate. One of his best-known works is *[Aniara](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Aniara)*, about a starship. Strictly speaking, *Aniara* isn't a novel, it's an epic poem. But it's book-length, and it's science-fictional enough that we carried it (along with many of the titles in Gilles' awesome list) at an SF bookstore I managed in the late 80s.

Comment: Also, the wiki page says that Aniara is one of his most famous works (unlike other situations where the sff works were not one of the author's primary works.)

Answer (score 2):

I'd say Marquez too.  Magical realism is basically just fantasy marketed towards readers who don't generally consider themselves people who "read fantasy".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 2):

Add [Winston Churchill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winston_Churchill) to the list -- Nobel Prize for literature, and he wrote some alternate history SF ("What If Lee Had Not Won The Battle Of Gettysburg").

Answer (score 2):

Hermann Hesse, Nobel 1946 for *The Glass Bead Game* aka *Magister Ludi* -- a work set about four centuries from now, centering on a game of intellect. Among the people it has inspired are the architect Christopher Alexander, whose *Pattern Language* is arguably a form of the Game, and the "father" of genetic algorithms, John Holland.

Speculative fiction should be proud to claim it.

Comment: And if you ask me, Banks' *The Player of Games* owes a lot to it (without in any way wishing to detract from what I personally find the best of all his Culture novels).  I'm not, however, aware that Banks expressed any views on the comparison.